# Can the Impervious Power Modifier be linked to unenhanced, natural Toughness?

Tags: character-creation, powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm building a new character whose powers come from a "cyber skin implant" that is pretty natural to her since it's now part of her body, giving her 12 Stamina without Enhanced Trait.

Her cyber skin also makes her highly resistant, and being PL 11 I don't want to invest more into Protection or Dodge Roll, giving her Impervious Toughness 14.

Now, I have been looking at examples, and unlike Strength, it seems that Impervious modifiers are always given to either Protection or Enhanced Stamina (Like in the Paragon example on Hero's Handbook, which makes me think, since his Impervious Rank is more than his enhanced stamina).

All in all, is it possible to use this effect as it is?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the text of **[Impervious](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-IMPERVIOUS-1-COST-PER-RANK-)** states that it only applies to enhanced Toughness, and there are examples in the book of extras being applied to "natural" abilities such as strength damage, let alone to enhanced ones such as your "cyber skin implant".

> A defense with this modifier is highly resistant. Any effect with a resistance difficulty modifier equal to or less than half the Impervious rank (rounded up) has no effect. So, for example, Impervious Toughness 9 ignores any Damage with a rank of 5 or less. Penetrating effects can overcome Impervious Resistance (see the Penetrating extra description).

Comment: On the Abilities chapter, it states that only Enhanced Traits can be modified by Power Effects; however it's contradictory to what's stated on Strength and Damage, since it points out the Strength Ability as it is can be linked to Power Effects, which confused me further on what can and can not be modified.